# RESTful API: how to tell whether an object retrieved by GET is editable (e.g, PUT-able) by the current user?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, frontend

Currently I set up a RESTful API backend using Django and I can list a set of articles by the following GET:

```
api/articles/
```

Also, I can get a single article by:

```
api/article/1/
```

Each article is owned by a certain user, and one user could have multiple articles of course.

On the frond end side, I present all the articles at loading of the page, and I hope the user who is logged in currently could see the articles that they own in a different style, e.g, outlined by a box, and has a associated "delete" or "edit" button.

This requires me to tell, after the retrieval of the articles, which ones are owned by the current user programmatically. One way of doing this is to check the current user id with the owner id. However I feel this is not a good choice as the user id is the check is done fully on the client side and may be not consistent with the actual server judgement.

Therefore, is there a way, to tell by looking at the response of the GET, (say, let the server return a property "editable=true/false") to get whether the current user could edit(PUT) the resource?

I understand that this could be done at the server side, by attaching such a property manually. However, I am just asking whether there is better/common practice.

I just started learning web development and I am sorry if the question sounds trivial. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach propriety manually as you suggested. The advance of this approach is that you dont need any other http request.

Second possibility might be, that your client intentionally request information about endpoint permissions. In this case I would suggest to use OPTIONS HTTP method. You send OPTIONS HTTP request to api/articles/1 and backend returns wanted info. This might be exactly what OPTIONS method and DRF metadata were made for.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/metadata/

Comment: The OPTIONS looks like what I am looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. You can thank me by accepting my answer, for any other users who will face similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a very interesting question.

Several options that come to me:

- You can add to the `GET api/article/1` response a HTTP header with this information i.e. `HTTP_METHODS_ALLOWED=PUT,PATH,DELETE`. Doing this way helps the API client because it does not need to know anything else. I think that this is not a good approach when more than one entity is returned.
- call to `OPTIONS api/article/1`. Allowed methods for that user on that resource can be returned but notice that, in my opinion,  this approach is not very good in terms of performance, because it duplicates the number of requests to the server.
- But what if the entity returned also contains information on the owner or it? can, in this case the client know which policy apply and try to figure out it by itself? notice that the policy can be obtained from another endpoint (just one call would be needed) or even with the login response. If your entities do not contain that kind of information, it could be also returned as a HTTP header (like first option above)